# Why does f1 = open(filename) keep erroring out? Is there a limit here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

why does f1= open(filethub) keep failing after several successful iterations?

```
import string
import shutil
import difflib

oldPath = input("What is the old directory?")
thubPath = input("What is the thub directory?")
toFile = input("What directory do you want the output file to go to? ")




def find(name, path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if name in files:
            tf = os.path.join(root, name)
            return tf 



def main():


    with open('difftext.txt', 'a')as outfile:

        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(oldPath):
            for file in files:
                fileold = file
                filethub = find(fileold, thubPath)
                fileoldn = os.path.join(root,fileold)
                print(filethub)
                f1 = open(filethub)
                f2 = open(fileoldn)
                outfile.write("|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||\n")
                outfile.write("\nComparing files \n")
                outfile.write("-----------------------------------\n")
                outfile.write(" > " + str(os.path.basename(filethub))+'\n')
                outfile.write(" < " +str(os.path.basename(fileoldn))+'\n')
                outfile.write("-----------------------------------\n")
                # Read the first line from the files
                f1_line = f1.readline()
                f2_line = f2.readline()

                # Initialize counter for line number
                line_no = 1

                # Loop if either file1 or file2 has not reached EOF
                while f1_line != '' or f2_line != '':

                    # Strip the leading whitespaces
                    f1_line = f1_line.rstrip()
                    f2_line = f2_line.rstrip()

                    # Compare the lines from both file
                    if f1_line != f2_line:

                        # If a line does not exist on file2 then mark the output with + sign
                        if f2_line == '' and f1_line != '':
                            outfile.write(">+" + "Line-%d" % int(line_no) + "--" + f1_line +'\n')
                        # otherwise output the line on file1 and mark it with > sign
                        elif f1_line != '':
                            outfile.write(">" + "Line-%d" % int(line_no) + "--" +  f1_line +'\n')

                        # If a line does not exist on file1 then mark the output with + sign
                        if f1_line == '' and f2_line != '':
                            outfile.write("<+" + "Line-%d" % int(line_no) + "--" +  f2_line +'\n')
                        # otherwise output the line on file2 and mark it with < sign
                        elif f2_line != '':
                            outfile.write("<" + "Line-%d" %  int(line_no) + "--" +  f2_line +'\n')

                        # Print a blank line
                        outfile.write('\n')

                    #Read the next line from the file
                    f1_line = f1.readline()
                    f2_line = f2.readline()


                    #Increment line counter
                    line_no += 1






if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

created this script to iterate over two directories containing two versions of the same files and prints out the differences in a single file.
oldPath and thubpath are user input values like

```
c:\Users\john\doe\work.txt
```

but keep getting this error after about 24iterations.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./line_diff.py", line 87, in <module>
    main()
  File "./line_diff.py", line 32, in main
    f1 = open(filethub)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Comment: How many files are in each directory?

Comment: Apparently `filethub` is `None`. [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print relevant data in the except suite - what happens? ... What is `find`?

Comment: @llama there are approximately 99 files in each directory.

Comment: @wwii I have done print and filethub is like the following

C:\Users\johndoe\Desktop\templates\report_prod\OUT_NEW_AGGREGATED-SMS-es_US.txt

Comment: @wwii 

`def find(name, path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if name in files:
            tf = os.path.join(root, name)
            return tf `

Comment: You need to make a [mre].

Comment: You are never closing these files.

Comment: `find` returns `None`. Which isn't surprising, because the way it is written, it will return `None` if the `name` is never `in files`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed comments above and want to note that you won't catch a None type with print():

Doing this:

```
>a = None
>print(a)
```

Will output `None` to the console.

I would follow the advice given of trying to catch the error.  You could do a simple check even.

Instead of:

```
f1 = open(filethub)
```

You could do:

```
if filethub:
    f1 = open(filethub)
```

But a try-catch for the whole bottom part might be better and it would have to go over pretty much the entire lower-part of your script.  You could even log the erroneous file for review later.

Answer (score 0):

1. The error message tells us that `open` was called with the parameter `None`.
2. The parameter comes from `filethub`, so `filethub` was `None`.
3. The last time `filethub` was assigned was by the `find` function.
4. So, the `find` function returned `None`.

You didn't include the `find` function, so i can't say anything about why. But you probably need to check if `find` returns `None`, and if so continue to the next iteration.

Comment: I have adjusted the original code to include all  to give a better picture 
after printing filthub , find is returning filename and path like
|
`C:\Users\johndoe\Desktop\templates\report_prod\OUT_NEW_AGGREGATED-SMS-es_US.txt`

Comment: also iterates successfully thru first 24 files so I know it is not returning `None`

Comment: Then it is returning None for the 25:th iteration. You print(filethub) before you open, Don't your console log "None" before the exception?

Comment: no it logs the os path and filename like | `C:\Users\johndoe\Desktop\templates\report_prod\OUT_NEW_AGGREGATED-SMS-es_US.txt` and I have verified the file exists in both directories and is named exactly the same. Also, the output file gets the filenames but then fails right before it begins reading lines.

Comment: That sounds impossible to me. Thanks for adding the full code. I don't have any more time to look at it right now.

Answer (score 0):

seems like error is within find function returning NoneType tho I am not sure why

found by adding `print(type(filethub))` before opening file and print  statement in find function.

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
heres your problem
<class 'NoneType'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./line_diff.py", line 90, in <module>
    main()
  File "./line_diff.py", line 34, in main
    f1 = open(filethub)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```